# Proving power rule for $x^n$ with arbitrary positive $n>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> How to prove that $\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$ for every $n>0$ (possibly fractional)?

#### Context

It was already shown that $\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$ for positive **integer** $n$.  My friend told me that the general case is pretty tricky because in order to prove it, I firstly need to be able to define $x^n$ in each case (rational and irrational real numbers). He made an example using the exponential function,  $$e^x = 1 + x + \frac12 x^2 + \frac16 x^3+\dots $$ However, I have not yet covered Taylor series or Maclaurin series.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70979/mathematics-engineering-how-do-you-prove-the-power-rule

Comment: This is all sorts of confusing. Is your issue with power rule or $e^x$? It's not clear at all.

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "the power rule", and what the power rule has to do with $e^{x\log(21/13)}$, and whether you know what a Maclaurin series is. There is no way to answer your question, when you haven't stated it clearly enough for people to figure out what your question is.

Comment: "It was shown that d/dx x^n = nx^n-1. But this was only for positive integers n. Assuming that n>0, let n be any real number. Prove that d/dx x^n = nx^n-1." My friend told me that this is pretty tricky because in order to prove it, I firstly need to be able to define each case (rational and irrational real numbers). He made an example by showing that e^x = 1 + x + 1/2x^2 + 1/6x^3.... I have not yet covered Taylor series or Maclaurin series

Comment: In any such argument, you need to define what $x^a$ means if $a$ is not rational. Either it is the unique continuous extension of $x^a$ (which is easy to define for rational $a$), or it is $\exp(a \ln(x))$. Showing that these definitions are equivalent is not a completely trivial matter. Proving the power rule from either of them is straightforward, although it is easier from the second definition.

Comment: I think, Lev, what you have put in the comment you should edit into the question. People shouldn't have to track through the comments to understand what the question is.

Answer (score 2):

We want to find the derivative of $x^a$, for positive $x$.  Note that $x^a=\exp(a\ln x)$. (For general $a$, that is precisely how $x^a$ is ordinarily *defined*.).

Differentiate, using the Chain Rule.

We get $\frac{a}{x}\exp(a\ln x)$. This is $\frac{a}{x}x^a$, which is $ax^{a-1}$.  That is the rule that we already knew held when $a$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Your definition of $x^a$ does not seem to help Lev. Either you are defining it as the irrational number raised to a (possibly) irrational number, in which case this suffers from the same problem as $x^a$, or you are defining it using a Taylor series which Lev does not know. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am assuming that the exponential function has been *defined* in the calculus course. Since OP has not reached power series, it may have been done in the way common in North American calculus books. Define $\ln x$ using an integral, and let $\exp$ be its inverse function. Then we can calculate the derivative of $\exp$, and the answer above becomes available. I agree that if $\exp$ has not been defined, then the answer is not helpful. One *could* define irrational powers as a limit of rational powers. For good reason it is not done that way: verifying the basic properties is too painful.

Comment: Ah, I knew I was missing something!