# Defining derivative of powers of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

We know that derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{(n-1)}$ if $n$ is an integer.
My question is how do we define derivative of $x^r$ is $r$ is an irrational number. For example what is the derivative of $x^\sqrt2$ or $x^\pi$?

Comment: Same rule applies

Comment: Well yes, the same rule applies.  Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mathematics Engineering: How do you prove the power rule?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70979/mathematics-engineering-how-do-you-prove-the-power-rule)

Comment: Nitpick.  We don't *define* anything.  We *derive* that $\frac {dx^r}{dx}= rx^{r-1}$ (assuming $r\ne 0$).  Now *how* we derive that.... well, that's a real question, isn't it!  But there are some great answers below but.... you should be aware we must first define (yes, *this* time define) what $x^r$ means in the first place....

Comment: @fleablood okay . Thanks for pointing that detail

Comment: BTW  the derivative of $x^{\sqrt 2}$ is $\sqrt 2 x^{\sqrt 2 -1}$ and the derivative of $x^\pi $ is $\pi x^{\pi -1}$ and .... you know,  I remember being a freshman in a calculus class thinking "Well, *that*'s convenient!  It cant be *that* simple, can it?".... so ... yeah... I remember the feeling....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We define $x^r$ as $x^r = e^{r \log x}$ so that
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dx} x^r &= \frac{d}{dx} e^{r \log x} \\&= \frac{r}{x} e^{r \log x} \\&= \frac{r}{x} x^r \\&= r x^{r-1}.
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you know the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem), you can get it right out of the definition in first semester calculus:

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^r-x^r}h&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\sum_{k\ge 1}\binom{r}kh^kx^{r-k}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{r^{\underline{k}}}{k!}h^kx^{r-k}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{r^{\underline{k}}}{k!}h^{k-1}x^{r-k}\\
&=r^{\underline 1}x^{r-1}+\lim_{h\to 0}\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac{r^{\underline{k}}}{k!}h^{k-1}x^{r-k}\\
&=rx^{r-1}+\lim_{h\to 0}h\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac{r^{\underline{k}}}{k!}h^{k-2}x^{r-k}\\
&=rx^{r-1}+0\\
&=rx^{r-1}
\end{align*}$$

Here $r^{\underline{k}}$ is a [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Comment: Profesor kindly help us here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780573/counting-words-with-a-condition

Comment: @James: My answer would be very similar to the one posted by **YJT**: your approach, if carried out correctly, does not lead to the result that you get, and the calculations get so involved, with subcases of subcases of subcases of ..., that it would literally be easier simply to list the acceptable sequences and count them. The key is to recognize that any given set of $6$ different digits can be arranged in increasing order in exactly one way, so there are exactly as many increasing sequences of $6$ digits as there are sets of $6$ different digits, namely, $\binom{10}6$.

Answer (score 1):

If you can differentiate $\ln$, you can argue as follows for any $r$:

$y = x^r; \tag 1$

$\ln y = r \ln x; \tag 2$

$\dfrac{y'}{y} = \dfrac{r}{x}; \tag 3$

$y' = \dfrac{ry}{x} = \dfrac{rx^r}{x} = rx^{r - 1}. \tag 4$

$OE\Delta$.

If you want to argue for $r$ rational but not an integer, you may also proceed as follows:

Set

$r = \dfrac{p}{q}, \; p, q \in \Bbb Z, \; q \ne 0; \tag 5$

then

$y = x^r = x^{p/q}; \tag 6$

so,

$y^q = x^p; \tag 7$

since $p$ and $q$ are integers, we may use the rule

$(z^n)' = nz^{n - 1}z', \tag 8$

and obtain

$qy^{q - 1}y' = px^{p - 1}, \tag 9$

whence

$y' = \dfrac{p}{q} \dfrac{x^{p - 1}}{y^{q - 1}}; \tag{10}$

now,

$y^{q - 1} = \dfrac{x^p}{y} = \dfrac{x^p}{x^{p/q}} = x^{p - p/q}, \tag{11}$

*via* which (10) yields

$y' = \dfrac{p}{q} \dfrac{x^{p - 1}}{x^{p - p/q}} = \dfrac{p}{q} x^{p/q - 1}. \tag{12}$

$OE\Delta$.

Comment: I could follow it except for the last part.  Looks greek to me.  Is that "QED"?

Comment: @mjw:  oh, that . . . $OE\Delta$ is the Greek acronym for the Greek phrase, "hos estai deixei", or "what was to be proved", the Greek equivalent of QED.  ***Cheers!***

Comment: Thank you!  Στην υγειά μας!

Comment: @mjw:  you are most welcome my friend!