# When does the derivative $f'(0)$ of $f(x)= (x^p)^{1/q}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Let $c=p/q$ where $p,q \in \mathbb Z$ are coprime and $q$ is odd.
>
> Define $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=x^c=(x^p)^{1/q}$.
>
> Question: When does $f^\prime(0)$ exist?

---

What I've tried (and where I'm stuck):

1. If $c<0$, then $0^c$ is undefined. So, we must have $c\ge 0$.
2. If $c=0$, then $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ and $f^\prime(0)=0$. (Trivial case.)
3. If $c=1$, then $f(x)=x$ for all $x$ and $f^\prime(0)=1$. (Trivial case.)
4. If $0<c<1$, then it seems that $f^\prime(0)$ is undefined. Is this true and how do I prove this?
5. If $c>1$, then it seems that $f^\prime(0)=0$. Is this true and how do I prove this?

Comment: Point (5) seems wrong. Consider $c=2=2/1$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang: You're right. I wonder what the correct claims should be then.

Comment: I have deleted my answer since it got too long and still failed to answer your question. Instead, I will leave a few hints: (a) Try the limit definition of the derivative $f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h$ and (b) Your guess for point (4) is correct, you will see why when you try (a), and for $c>1$, you will always have $f'(0) = 0$, which you will also see from (a).

Comment: @BenjaminWang: I've deleted my old points 5 & 6 and now replaced it with a new point 5.

Comment: Why not just evaluate $\left.c x^{c-1}\right|_{x=0}$?. If $0\le c\le 1$, then $x^{c-1}$ has a negative power and as $x\to0$, the limit diverges while for $c>1$, the power is positive, so as $x\to0$, $x^{c-1}\to0$

Comment: Hint: Let $c>0$, then we want to study the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^{c-1}.$$

Comment: @ТymaGaidash :  It's possible that part of the point of the problem is checking the fine details of whether $f'(x) = cx^{c-1}$ is actually correct when $x=0$.  In particular, when $c = 0$, this formula suggests that $f'(0)$ is undefined, since $0 \cdot 0^{-1}$ is normally taken to be undefined, yet this course is using $0^0 = 1$ so that really $f'(0) = 0$ when $c = 0$, as in point (2) from the question.  (And if you leave $0^0$ undefined, then the same issue appears when $c = 1$.)  So can we really use the formula to conclude that $f'(0)$ is undefined when $0 < c < 1$?

Comment: @TobyBartels Would the $\lim\limits_{x\to0}$ work, as implied by the comment?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash :  It gives the correct answer, but if you want to make that into a proof, then it's a little subtle.  For example, if you take $ f ( x ) = 0 ^ x $ (still using $ 0 ^ 0 = 1 $ so that $ f $ is defined but discontinuous at $ 0 $), then $ \lim \limits _ { x \to 0 } f ' ( x ) = 0 $, but $ f ' ( 0 ) $ is undefined.  There is a theorem (using the Mean-Value Theorem) that if $ f $ is continuous at $ a $ and differentiable near $ a $ and $ \lim \limits _ { x \to a } f ' ( x ) $ converges, then $ f ' ( a ) $ exists and equals this limit, but this may be a bit too advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of the derivative,
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.
$$

For the function $f(x) = (x^p)^{1/q},$ evaluating the derivative at $x = 0,$
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}
 = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(h^p)^{1/q} - (0^p)^{1/q}}{h}.
$$

In order for $(0^p)^{1/q}$ to be defined, we need to rule out the possibility that
$p < 0.$ This leaves just the following two cases:

**Case $p > 0.$** In this case $0^p = 0$, so for $(0^p)^{1/q}$ to be defined we require that $q > 0$ and we find that $(0^p)^{1/q} = 0.$ Therefore
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(h^p)^{1/q} - 0}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} h^{(p/q)-1}.
$$
If $p < q$ then $\frac pq - 1 < 0$ and $h^{(p/q)-1}$ has no finite limit as $h\to 0.$

If $p=q$ (which happens when $p = q = 1$) then $\frac pq - 1 = 0$, so $h^{(p/q)-1} = 1$ for all $h \neq 0$ and the limit is $f'(0) = 1.$

If $p > q$ then $\frac pq - 1 > 0$, so $h^{(p/q)-1}$ goes to $0$ as $h\to 0$ and the limit is $f'(0) = 0.$

So in this case we require $p \geq q > 0.$

**Case $p = 0.$** In this case $f'(0)$ exists only if $(0^0)^{1/q}$ exists, which requires $q \neq 0$ and also depends on the definition of $0^0.$ If $0^0 = 1$ then
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(h^p)^{1/q} - (0^p)^{1/q}}{h}
 = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1^{1/q} - 1^{1/q}}{h}
 = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0.
$$
If $0^0$ is defined as anything else then we end up with the limit of $\frac{1 - 0^0}h,$ which is undefined, and of course if $0^0$ is not defined then the limit cannot exist.

Note that in this case the "coprime" condition requires that $q = \pm 1.$

**Conclusion:** $f'(0)$ is defined in two cases:
$$p \geq q > 0.$$
$$p = 0,\ q = \pm 1,\ \text{provided that $0^0=1$.}$$
Moreover, $f'(0) = 0$ except in the case $p = q > 0,$ where $f'(0) = 1.$

So your claim number 2 is correct as long as we accept that $0^0 = 1,$
and the other four claims are correct regardless of the definition of $0^0.$

Comment: Thanks! (I should've specified that I use $0^0=1$. But thanks for covering the other possibilities too!)

Answer (score 3):

Let us set $c=\frac{p}{q}$. **We evaluate for $c>0$.** **First, if $p<0$, then $x^p$ is not defined at $x=0$, and thus neither is $f(0)$. So let us assume that $p>0$ and thus [as $c$ is positive] that $q$ is also positive.** Then first note the following:

$$ \text{For $p$ even  } f(x) = (x^p)^{1/q} = |x|^{c}. $$
$$ \text{For $p$ odd  } f(x) =(x^p)^{1/q}, {\text{ where} }$$
$$ (x^p)^{1/q} = |x|^{c} {\text{ for $x\ge 0$, and }}$$
$$ (x^p)^{1/q} = -|x|^{c} {\text{ for $x < 0$}}.$$

[Note that as $c>0$, that $0^c$ is well-defined. **Note that $0^a$ is well-defined, $0^a=0$ for all positive numbers $a$.** So then, $f(0)$ is also well-defined [for $p$ positive], and $f(0)=0$, whether or not $p$ is odd or even. ] So let us now use this:

Then note that $f'(x)$
satisfies
$${\text{For $p$ even, }} f'(x) = cx^{c-1} \ {\text{ for $x > 0$.} }$$
$${\text{For $p$ even, }} f'(x) = -c|x|^{c-1} \ {\text{ for $x< 0$.} }$$
$${\text{For $p$ odd, }} f'(x) = cx^{c-1} \ {\text{ for $x > 0$.} }$$
$${\text{For $p$ odd, }} f'(x) = c|x|^{c-1} \ {\text{ for $x< 0$.} }$$

**If $c=\frac{p}{q}$ satisfies $c>1$:**
First note that $f$, whether $p$ is even or odd, is continuous at $x=0$. *So then $f'(0)$ is well-defined,
and the equation $f'(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} c|x|^{c-1}$ holds, **if** the limits $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0-} \pm c|x|^{c-1}$ [the $\pm$ depending on whether $p$ is even or odd] and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} c|x|^{c-1}$ are both well-defined and are the same.* However, indeed, these left-hand and right-hand limits clearly are well-defined and the same and in fact both evaluate to $c0^{c-1}=0$. So then indeed, $f'(0)$ is well-defined, and $f'(0)=0$ for $c>1$.

**If $c =\frac{p}{q}$ satisfies $0<c<1$**: Then $c<1$, note $c-1$ is less than $0$ so $|f'(x)|=c|x|^{c-1}$ blows up around the neighborhood of $x=0$. So $f'(0)$ does not exist.

So yes, your conjectures 4) and 5) are both correct.

Comment: *note that $f$, whether $p$ is even or odd, is continuous at $x=0$. So then $f^\prime(0)$ is well-defined* -- How does $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ imply $f^\prime(0)$ is well-defined?

Comment: The conditions for $f'(0)$ to be well-defined are *both* $f$ to be continuous at $x=0$ *and* the right-hand and left-hand limits for $f'(x)$ to be the same at $x=0$. We have both for $c>1$.

Comment: @user182601 The conditions for f′(0) to be well-defined are not just $f$ being continuous at $x=0$, it is instead **both** $f$ to be continuous at $x=0$, **and** the right-hand and left-hand limits for $f′(x)$ to exist be the same at $x=0$. We have both for $c>1$.

Comment: Using limit of derivative to conclude existence of derivative is a roundabout way and involves the use of mean value theorem. The definition of derivative offers a much simpler solution.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Well but the mean-value thm is not used though. The issue is that a priori $f$ is one well-behaved [continuous, differentiable] function $f_1$ on the nonnegative reals, and $f$ is another such function $f_2$ on the negative reals. We observe that these two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$  go to the same limit at $x=0$ and their derivatives also go to the same limit. And that suffices to show the existence of $f'(0)$.

Answer (score -1):

Lets start from beginning

We have a function
$$f(x) = x^{p/q}$$
Let
c = $\dfrac{p}{q}$

Differentiating this function with respect to x
$$ f'(x) = cx^{c-1}$$
For c < ${0}$
$$f'({x}) = cx^{-(c+1)}$$
$$f'({x}) = \dfrac{c}{x^{c+1}}$$
$$\therefore f'({0}) = \infty$$
For c= ${0}$
$$ f'(x) = 0\times x^{(0-1)}$$
$$ f'(x) = 0 $$
$$ \therefore f'(0) = 0$$
For  ${0}\le c \le 1$
$$ f'(x) = cx^{c-1} $$
$$\therefore f'({0}) = \infty $$
For c = ${1}$
$$f'(x) = x^{(1-1)}$$
$$\therefore f'(0) = 1$$
For c > 1
$$ f'(x) = cx^{c-1}$$
$$ \therefore f'({0}) = {0} $$

Therefore f'(${0}$) is not defined for c $<{0}$

Comment: You assume $f^\prime(x)=cx^{c-1}$ for all $x$ including $x=0$. But my question is exactly about how to find $f^\prime(0)$.

Comment: You write $ f'(x) = 0\times x^{(0-1)}$ $ \therefore f'(x) = {0} $. But $0\times 0^{(0-1)}$ is undefined.

Comment: For $c=0$, the derivative is $0$.

Comment: No for c = 0 derivative will be infinity or undefined.
$$f'(0) = 0 \times 0^{(0-1)}$$
$$f'(0) = 0 \times 0^{(-1)}$$
$$f'(0) = \frac{0}{0}$$
This is undefined

Comment: For $c=0$ it depends on how you define (or don't define) $0^0$. If $0^0=1$ then $f'(x)=0$ everywhere including at $x=0$, despite what the power rule says.